# Thermal Camera Images

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

I connected the `Adafruit AMG8833` and I got it to turn on, but I cannot take pictures with `pygame`, `pi camera` or `opencv`. I was trying to take a picture with `open cv`, but I just got an error message.

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

I was trying to capture an image with the following code:

```
$ raspistill -o output.jpg
```

but that's when the error showed up.

Comment: Would you please add your code in your question.

Comment: did you turn on camera in configuration  - `$ raspi-config` ?

Comment: maybe it is incorrectly connected in camera's port. I had similar error with standard camera and I had to disconnect and connect it again but more carefully.